# How to launch calabash-android on OS X? (Ruby gems dependency error)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, calabash, calabash-android

I've successfully generated file tree via `calabash-android gen`

After that I've tried to run tests:

```
calabash-android run ../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

But got error:

```
Unable to activate calabash-android-0.9.0, because json-2.0.2 conflicts with json (~> 1.8) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

I've installed json 1.8.6 via `gem install 'json' -v 1.8.6`

and now gem list json outputs me

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)
multi_json (1.12.1)
```

But error `Unable to activate calabash-android-0.9.0, because json-2.0.2 conflicts with json (~> 1.8) (Gem::ConflictError)` throwed again. Where I am wrong?

**UPD**

I've tried to solve problem as described here github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1260 but osx says that I cant remove 2.0.2 version because it's default

```
MacBook-Pro-MacBook:calabash zub3r$ gem uninstall -Vax --force --no-abort-on-dependent json
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    json is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /Users/zub3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global json
MacBook-Pro-MacBook:calabash zub3r$ gem uninstall -i /Users/zub3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global json

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    json-1.8.6

calabash-android-0.9.0 depends on json (~> 1.8)
cucumber-1.3.20 depends on json (~> 1.7, development)
luffa-2.0.0 depends on json (~> 1.8)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  ^CERROR:  Interrupted
MacBook-Pro-MacBook:calabash zub3r$ gem uninstall -i /Users/zub3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global json --version 2.0.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Comment: It sounds similar to this issue https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/issues/1260

Comment: I tried. Not helped. Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by using `bundler`

```
bundle init
```

Gemfile content replaced with

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'calabash-android'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue,I had downgraded my ruby version and it got solved.
Please find the solution below

```
$ gem -v
2.0.3
$ gem list rubygems-update
$ gem uninstall -v 2.0.3 rubygems-update 

$ gem install -v 1.8.24 rubygems-update
$ update_rubygems
$ gem -v
```

1.8.24